# Como alterar o titulo da WebView

Tags: android

Estou a fazer uma app em que utilizo uma WebView. A duvida é como posso alterar o texto que aparece "WebViewApp" quando abro a app.

Answer (score 2):

Altere o arquivo androidmanifest.xml

> Tag: Application
>
> Propriedade android:label

```
<application
    android:label="NomeDaSuaAplicação"
```